# How Automatic Type Inference works if the constructor parameter is not generic

Tags: java

Case 1:

```
class Gen3<T extends Number> {
    T val;

    <T extends String> Gen3(String ob){

    }
}
```

Here compiler doesn't give any error, but it should give right? Because here are  two contradicting bounds for T. Please help me in understanding this.

Case 2:

```
class Gen3<T extends Number> {
    T val;

    <T extends String> Gen3(String ob) {

    }           
}
```

Suppose if I write following to test the above class

```
Gen<Integer> a = new Gen<>("r");
```

Now how automatic type inference would work here?

Please help in understanding this.

Comment: Case 1: why should it give an error, they are just separate type variables. It's ill-advised to do this, but there's nothing wrong with it per se.

Comment: Case 2: what's the difference in the Gen class, other than the indentation?

Comment: Case 1 is nothin but *shadowing* one T with another T. Its like you called the the outer T1 and the inner T2. That is how the compiler looks at it.

Comment: `T extends String`? `String` is final, so your second `T` can only be `String`.

Comment: for case 1: T should be consistent throughout the class definition, but here are two contradicting definitions for T

for case 2: Please read the question carefully

Comment: @Johannes it's still legal to write that.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, but useless.

Comment: @RishabShinghal Perhaps you intended the two cases to have a difference, but currently they are identical.

Comment: @Rishab: "T should be consistent" says you. The language spec says otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

There are no two contradicting bounds of `T`. There are two type variables that happen to have the same name. In the constructor, the type parameter `T` hides the type parameter of the class level.

Note that the issue is not with the different type bounds. If you actually try to do something with the type parameter, such as:

```
class Gen3<T extends Number> {
    T val;
    <T extends Number> Gen3(T ob) {
        val = ob;
    }
}
```

This won't pass compilation even if both `T`s have the same type bound, since the type parameter of `ob` is different than the type parameter of `val`.

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing that.

But for Case 2: how automatic type inference would work? Can you please help me in understanding  that?

Comment: @RishabShinghal The outer `T` is inferred as it would be for any generic class. The inner `T` is unused and uninferred.

Comment: I am clear about outer and inner T now. I am asking about, 

Gen<Integer> a=new Gen<>("r");

Here in this statement, how diamond reference would be doing automatic type inference.

Comment: @RishabShinghal `Gen<Integer> a=new Gen<>("r");` is equivalent to `Gen<Integer> a=new Gen<Integer>("r");`

Answer (score 2):

*"Because here are two contradicting bounds for T"* - no. There simply a two separate definitions of `T` that have nothing to with each other. The `T` on the constructor hides the `T` of the class, same with local variables vs. fields of the same name. A "proper" IDE will tell you that the inner `T` hides the outer `T` and is unused.

Answer (score 1):

This "use case" of Generics doesn't make sense in multiple aspects. With the `<T extends String>` clause you introduce a type variable that you don't use and don't give the compiler a chance to replace it with a concrete type in a given call situation.

Your definition is equivalent to the following (I just renamed the two different type variables to have different names, making the discussion easier):

```
class Gen3<T extends Number> {
    T val;
    <U extends String> Gen3(String ob) {

    }
}
```

The `<U extends String>` clause tells the compiler: "The following constructor will use a type parameter `U`, and I only allow `U` to be `String` or a subclass of `String`". As others already said, String is final, so `U` can only be `String`, so it isn't really a variable type, and declaring a variable type that can't vary doesn't make sense. I'll continue with a modified version:

```
class Gen3<T extends Number> {
    T val;
    <U extends Collection> Gen3(String ob) {

    }
}
```

If you do `Gen<Integer> a=new Gen<Integer>("r");`, how should the compiler find out the concrete class to replace `U` with? The `<Integer>` part applies to the `T` variable, so it doesn't help for `U`. As you don't refer to `U` in any of the arguments, there's no hint for the compiler.

The idea of Generics is that a class has some elements where you want to allow for varying types, and allow the compiler to flag misuse, e.g. add an `Integer` to a `List<String>`:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add(new Integer(12345));
```

Here, the compiler can match the generic `List<E>` type parameter `E` to be a `String` (from the `List<String>` declaration). In this context, the gegeric `List.add(E e)` method declaration becomes an `add(String e)`, and doesn't match the usage with `new Integer(12345)`, which isn't a `String`, allowing the compiler to flag the error.

**Summary:**

Introduce a type parameter only if you give the compiler a chance to deduce it from the call arguments.